# WordPress : Sort by multiple meta keys with wp_query

Tags: wordpress, sorting, custom-fields, date-sorting

I´m working on a event website with a calender of all events sort by two customfields

1. date_start - the day of the event. the data ist stored like this 
   20160622 for today > 22/06/2016
2. time_start - the time the event beginns on this day. the data ist stored for german use. 
   10am = 10:00 / 3pm = 15:00 / 8pm = 20:00

To sort the events only by date_start works great.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'veranstaltungen',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'cat' => '1,2,3,4,5',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key' => 'date_start',
            'orderby'  => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC'),
            'order' => 'DESC'   
        ));
```

Now im looking for a solution the sort also with the customfield of time_start.
When an events starts on 3pm (15:00) it shouldn´t be shown after the 8pm (20:00) event.

What is in my case the right use of 'meta_query' to sort the customflieds by date and time?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use `meta_query`. Try to do something like below.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'veranstaltungen',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => '1,2,3,4,5',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
                'key'     => 'date_start',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'time_start',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => DESC,
            ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. And that DESC and ASC is not a string is an indication that the code doesn't run anywhere